# Regex with pattern match before OR after in one regex?

Tags: regex

If I am looking for anchor words in a match e.g. the word color in a sentence IF there is a color in that sentence but the match is fine before OR after:

- the color red
- a red color

Can I do this in one regex or two I need two:

```
(Color (Red|Blue|Orange))
```

https://regex101.com/r/iT4nN6/1

```
((Red|Blue|Orange) Color)
```

https://regex101.com/r/iT4nN6/2

Comment: Maybe [`(?|(Red|Blue|Orange) Color|Color (Red|Blue|Orange))`](https://regex101.com/r/wG1lC9/1)? Is it for PCRE/Boost?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think this requires at the end with optional at the beginning?

Comment: Could you re-phrase? I only suggested a regex for an engine that supports branch reset. Does yours? What language is this code for?

Comment: Can you clearly specify example inputs and outputs?

Comment: @Szymon i hope this helps: https://regex101.com/r/iT4nN6/5

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I believe it will be in pho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP PCRE regex syntax, you can leverage the `(?J)` modifier that lets use the same names for different capture groups:

```
(?J)(?<colorword>Color)\h+(?<color>Reddish|Red|Blue|Orange)|(?<color>Reddish|Red|Blue|Orange)\h+(?<colorword>Color)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yS1dB7/1)

[PHP demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdHpQaXN5S2pBZ0E):

```
$clrw = '(?<colorword>Color)';
$clr = '(?<color>Reddish|Red|Blue|Orange)';
$re = '~(?J)' . $clrw . '\h+' . $clrw . '|' . $clr . '\h+' . $clrw . '~i'; 
$str = " I WANT TO EXTRACT CAPTURING GROUP 2 AS COLOR AND I DO:\nand  love the Color Red\n \nI WANT TO EXTRACT CAPTURING GROUP 2 AS COLOR BUT I DONT AS I HAVE TO REVERSE THE GROUPS TI ((Red|Blue|Orange) Color):\nit had a reddish color\n\nI DON'T WANT ANYTHING BECAUSE IT ISN'T PRECEDED OR FOLLOWED BY THE WORD COLOR\nit is a red dawn \nI took the red eye home\nit was the color red"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches); $i++) {
    echo $matches[$i]["color"] . ": " . $matches[$i]["colorword"] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
Red: Color
reddish: color
red: color
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a single regex:

`((Red|Orange|Blue) Color|Color (Red|Orange|Blue)`

If things get more complicated, then it will be harder to maintain; you need to update the list of colors in two places. It might be easier to do the two components separately, looking for one only in the results of the other, depending on your exact situation.